# bash script: parsing grep command output and passing to second action

Tags: regex, bash, grep, pipe

```
docker-compose down
```

sometimes crashes, leaving behind busy resources which prevent fully unmounting and remounting docker volumes

i can manually fix this by doing something like:

```
grep -l 12c8b1e0d711db12b /proc/*/mountinfo
```

which gives:

```
/proc/12053/mountinfo
/proc/16127/mountinfo
...
/proc/16139/mountinfo
/proc/16192/mountinfo
```

etc

where each number is the process PID now i can do

```
kill -9 16139 12053 ... 16139
```

I'm trying to put this into a bash script to help automate this process.

Question: 
I need to pass the output of grep command through the correct regex to parse out the 2nd argument (the int value in each line of /proc/16192/mountinfo). 
The I need to assemble these into a space separated string, and finally pass this string as argument to `kill`.

I'm not really sure how to approach this in bash scripting

Any and all pointers welcomed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use straight up bash scripting with parameter substitution to extract the process id and put them in an array and then use `kill` on it.

For example:

```
declare -a process
for t1 in $(grep -l 12c8b1e0d711db12b /proc/*/mountinfo); do
   t2="${t1#/proc/}" # remove /proc/ from beginning
   pid="${t2%/mountinfo}" # remove /mountinfo from the end
   process+=("$pid")
done

kill -9 "${process[@]}"
```

Comment: Good approach, can I suggest `process+=("${t1//[^[:digit:]]/}")` though?

Comment: Sure. It is better performant and removes the unnecessary creation of temp variables. I would prefer pid="${t1//[^[:digit:]]/}" for the sake of readability instead of doing everything in one line.

Comment: seems to work great, and way less complicated than i was expecting.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself wanting to parse the output of grep, sed, etc. you should really consider just using awk instead.

```
procs=$(awk '/12c8b1e0d711db12b/{split(FILENAME,f,"/"); print f[3]}' /proc/*/mountinfo)
[ -n "$procs" ] && kill -9 "$procs"
```